# in figure find $x $ ? with The brief solution!

Tags: geometry

in figure find $x $ ?

with The brief solution!
thanks !!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyQp1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two circles are tangent to each other:
[image]